# Cannot transition between height:0 and max-height:500px;

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I understand it is not possible to transition between 0 and auto heights, and the solution presented is to use `max-height` at a value greater than the box would ever be in order to make the box grow to the correct height to contain all it's elements.

However, when I try to add a transition between `height:0;` and `max-height:500px` I get no transition.

I've tried again with simply `height:0;` and `height:500px` which *should* be transitionable, but it doesn't seem to be.

How can I transition `height`? is it not possible?

## JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tzgevx8e/

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-icon">click me</div>
<div id="contact-form" class="closed">
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-icon').click(function(){
                $('.menu-icon').addClass('active');
                var form_status = $('#contact-form').attr('class');
                if (form_status == 'closed'){
                    openFooter();
                }else{
                    closeFooter();
                }
            });

            function openFooter(){
                $('#contact-form').removeClass('closed');
            }

            function closeFooter(){
                $('#contact-form').addClass('closed');
                $('.menu-icon').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
```

**CSS**

```
#contact-form.closed{display:none;height: 0px;overflow: hidden;transition:all 0.5s ease-in;}
#contact-form{display:block;height:200px;overflow:hidden;transition:all 0.5s ease-in;background-color:#2e263d;color:#fff;padding:20px 0 40px 0;}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle of transitioning `height:auto;` without needing to use `max-height`...this may help as well. http://jsfiddle.net/n5XfG/2596/

Comment: Why not transition between `max-height:0` and `max-height:500px`? Does that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...your CSS was out of whack.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tzgevx8e/3/

CSS

```
#contact-form  {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
}
#contact-form.open {
    height:200px;
    background-color:#2e263d;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px 0 40px 0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.menu-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#contact-form').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yikes, that looks ugly. To be honest you would be better using a checkbox and label with a bit of CSS to replace all that jQuery nonsense. While @VIDesignZ has solved your problem, I feel as though this is a better solution:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label + div {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
}
input:checked + label:after {
  content: " To Hide";
}
input+ label:after {
  content: " To Show";
}
div {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #2e263d;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id=cb>
<label for=cb>Click Here</label>
<div>
  Hello. This is some stuff.
</div>
```

Comment: Decent solution though you now have turned all that jquery nonsense into css nonsense! ;)

Comment: Hahaha true ;) But then again CSS has that native browser boost so it will be faster, who doesn't like speed?! :D

Comment: The “checkbox hack” has some accessibility issues though (especially when it comes to keyboard navigation.)

Comment: @CBroe Ah I didn't think of that, thanks for pointing that out. I'll look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

just change the css as i mention below no need to change anything else.

```
#contact-form.closed{
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  padding: 0
}

#contact-form{
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #2e263d;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
}
```

Comment: thanx Ana for formatting next time i will post after formatting so it's easy to read.